# If S is subset of S', then lin(S) is subset of lin(S')

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have this problem on my linear algebra course, which I don't know how to start solving. The problem follows:

Let V be a vector space and S, S' ⊆ V. Prove right or wrong that S ⊆ S' implies⟹ lin(S) ⊆ lin(S').

The further question is: Does the answer change when examining proper subsets?

That is, does S ⊂ S' imply⟹ lin(S) ⊂ lin(S')?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Do you understand all the definitions involved? Does lin(S) mean the linear span of the set S? The statement *does* hold for subsets, but not for proper subsets.

Comment: I understand that S and S' are subspaces (subsets) of V and lin(S) and lin(S') are linear spans. I was also thinking that the statement holds for subsets, but not for proper subsets. However I can't figure out how to prove this.